# Counterexample: Differentiable function everywhere but 0, however limit f' exists at 0

Tags: real-analysis

True or False:
There is a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus{0}$ but not at $0$, for which $f'$ has a limit at $0$

I think its true. I immediately think of y=|x| but the limit DNE at 0.
Any clue? Thank you